# comparing azure AD And AWS cognito

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

All ,

1. what is the Microsoft equivalent of  aws cognito ?  is it azure AD.
2. Is azure AD authentication and identity management service ?
3. Is azure AD coupled with active directory service ?
   4.can someone pls point me to side by side comparison of the two

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft equivalent of aws cognito is Azure Active Directory B2C. For more details, checkout service comparison page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services#security-identity-and-access

Answer (score 0):

As per 2024 [Microsoft Entra External ID](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/business/identity-access/microsoft-entra-external-id) is the equivalent of Cognito in Azure Cloud.